# What is the difference between BY CONTENT and BY VALUE in a CALL statement?

Tags: cobol, calling-convention

What is the difference between `BY CONTENT` and `BY VALUE` in a `CALL` statement in COBOL?

Comment: Question should mention OS and compiler. Answers currently include details that are not always true for different compilers. E.g., BY VALUE isn't always limited to {an "integer" or a one-byte alphanumeric value) and literals, and any valid data type can be passed BY VALUE in at least some COBOL compilers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`BY CONTENT` on a `CALL` will copy the content of the identifier to a compiler-managed area of storage, which will then be passed to the CALLed program "by reference" implicitly.

This means the CALLed program can change the data, but no change made in the CALLed program will affect the original data in the CALLing program.

Any identifier, of any size valid for the compiler, can be used BY CONTENT (subject to any limits, if existing, which are documented for the specific compiler - you never know).

Although you *can* change the value in a CALLed program, it would seem a bit obscure to do so, at best.

`BY VALUE` is an entirely different beast. It is very limited, in that the value "passed" can be either an "integer" or a one-byte alphanumeric value. It can also be a literal.

The `PROCEDURE DIVISION USING ...` has to know, in the case of BY VALUE, that is is so, by specifying it in an equivalent manner to the CALL. BY REFERENCE and BY CONTENT on the CALL are both BY REFERENCE on the PROCEDURE DIVISION USING.

How this is implemented is down to the specific compiler. IBM Enterprise COBOL puts the value itself in the "parameter list".

Comment: @ven, thanks, although I think I should look for opportunities to use my new word "manged".

Comment: Surely, the developing field of COBOL will have some opportunities for you to do that :-).

Answer (score 1):

Passing parameters by content is the same as passing by reference, except that the data is not copied back into the COBOL memory when the call has completed. Meaning that the original variable cannot be edited by the Called unit.

So the difference between `BY CONTENT` and `BY VALUE` is that in the case of `BY VALUE`only the value gets passed and therefor not all kind of variables can be passed this way while `BY CONTENT` the pointer of a copied variable gets passed and in this way every type of variable can be passed.

See: http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.visualcobol.eclipseux%2FGUID-EB09203C-3873-4DBE-9298-0C353BC0701A.html

> **By Reference:**
>
> When a parameter is passed by reference, a copy of the item in the JVM
>   COBOL is passed to the native code. When the call to the native has
>   finished, any changes to the information made in the native code are
>   copied back to the JVM COBOL. However, this does mean that memory is
>   shared between the JVM and native environments. In fact, what is
>   actually passed to the native code is a pointer to the copied data.
>   This is useful if you are calling non-COBOL programs. The implications
>   of this are very important, particularly in multi-threaded
>   environments. Any changes to reference parameters are not visible to
>   the JVM COBOL calling program until the call has completed.
>   Arbitrarily complex group items (within the memory limitations) can be
>   passed by reference. The group definition must be identical in the
>   native and JVM COBOL source code and it must not contain USAGE POINTER
>   items. Strings (java.lang.Strings) and tables (java.lang.byte arrays)
>   can be passed by reference. All other objects (types that inherit from
>   java.lang.Object, including valuetypes) cannot be passed by reference
>   (or by value - see below).
>
> **By Content**
>
> Passing parameters by content is the same as passing by reference,
>   except that the data is not copied back into the JVM COBOL memory when
>   the call has completed. Any item that can be passed by reference can
>   be passed by content.
>
> **By Value**
>
> In JVM COBOL, the only items that can be passed by value are as
>   follows: binary-long - the recommended type for passing by value pic
>   x(4) comp-x pic (9)9 comp pic s(9)9 comp pic (9)9 comp-5 pic s(9)9
>   comp-5

Comment: I don't agree with you, JVM or no JVM it works the same, and contains the same information as the accepted answer.

Comment: Well, from the called programs point of view, they are identical.  That they don't get copied back is kind of a backwards way of saying they are copied to disposable storage and any changes will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer to more reflect the question.